# Does $n^n \geq n$ and $n! \geq 1$ prove that $\frac{1}{n} \geq \frac{n!}{n^n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, proof-writing

Can I use the fact that $n^n \geq n$ and $n! \geq 1$ to prove that $\frac{1}{n} \geq \frac{n!}{n^n}$ where $n \in \mathbb N$?

If not, what can I do? I’m really stuck on this one

Comment: what you are assumed to solve the problem is correct.now if you use this two assumption in a right way you can solve it.

Comment: The inequality $n!\geq1$ is the wrong way around to be useful. By way of analogy, can you use the fact that $4\geq2$ and $20\geq1$ to prove $\frac12\geq\frac{20}{4}$?

Comment: $$\frac{n!}{n^n}=\frac{2\cdot 3\cdots (n-1)\cdot n}{n^n}\leq\frac{n\cdot n\cdots n\cdot n}{n^n}\leq\frac{n^{n-1}}{n^n}=\frac 1n$$

Comment: Why is $\frac{n \cdot n \cdot \cdot \cdot n \cdot n}{n^n} \leq \frac{n^{n-1}}{n^n}$? Doesn't $\frac{n \cdot n \cdot \cdot \cdot n \cdot n}{n^n} = \frac{n^n}{n^n} = 1$

Answer (score 2):

You can use those inequalities but they are not sufficient (see  stewbasic's comment). 
Consider that
$$\frac{n!}{n^n}=\frac{1}{n}\cdot\left( \frac{2}{n}\cdot \frac{3}{n}\cdots \frac{n-1}{n}\cdot \frac{n}{n}\right).$$
Now recall that if $0<a\leq 1$ and $0<b\leq  1$ then also the product $0<a\cdot b\leq  1$.

Can you take it from here?